# Page layout is traversing using geometry package

Tags: margins, geometry

I wanted to add 1.25 inch gap on left margin.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=1.25 in,
 top=1 in,
 bottom = 1 in,
 right = 1in
 }
```

This is adding 1.25 inch on left one page then next page 1.25 inch on right side. This is pretty weired. Anyone know any solution? I am on a tight schedule.

Comment: Please always post compilable code. Mere fragments are of little use in most cases and never as useful as something people can test. And please don't add arbitrary tags. This had nothing to do with either LaTeX3 or Overleaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This MUST be a duplicate, but the search function makes things too difficult to find.

`book` is double-sided by default. That means margins are flipped on even pages. If your document is one-sided, you don't want this, so tell `book` and `geometry` this is single-sided.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=1.25 in,
  top=1 in,
  bottom = 1 in,
  right = 1in
}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Life saver